# To store a Binary Tree in a File

Tags: file, binary-tree, store

```
How to store a binary tree in a file & then read back.(Its not necessarily a BST)

               A
            /     \
          B        C
        /   \
       D    E
```

For this we could have something like (A(B(D),(E)),(C)) for storing it in the file.
But what if you hav  ‘(‘ ,  ’,’ characters in data of tree node . Then how to store it so that we could retrieve it and construct the original BT.

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind or are you looking for generic solution?

Answer (score 1):

The answer remains in your question. You can store the characters within quotes, and while reading those, whenever you encounter a quote mark, keep reading until you find the next, then drop the quotes. And if you have quotes in the tree, you can escape them with some other special character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store fairly arbitrary data structures as a text file, consider using [YAML](http://yaml.org). There are encoder/decoder libraries available for most languages.

If this is for homework or you're wondering how you'd implement it yourself, use the common idea of [escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). See the examples in that link if you're not familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You must know what separators you can use. For example, assuming that blank space is the separator, i.e. the node data do not contain blank spaces, you can use this representation for storing in the file : ( A ( B ( D ) (E) ) ( C ) )
You can replace the blank space by any other suitable separators.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd have brackets in node - `(` or `)`, you'd have to [escape them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), e.g. with backslash `\`. Of course you'd always have to check for backslash when you are parsing the data. This would slow down your parser a bit, so if speed would matter a lot, you should choose a separator character that is not valid node character at all.